# How to stop Resharper from removing [CanBeNull] when typing "?" at the end of a reference type name?

Tags: c#, resharper, nullable

I am going through the process of converting my .Net 4.8 (not Core!) projects to use the new C# 8 "nullable reference" feature.

To do so, I am changing each source code file in turn by adding `#nullable enable` and decorating all nullable references with a `?` suffix. This allows me to convert all my code in a piecemeal fashion to use the new feature.

Now consider the following method in a source file with `#nullable enable` specified:

```
#nullable enable

[CanBeNull] public static string Test([CanBeNull] string arg)
{
    return arg;
}
```

If I type a '?' after either of the `string` declarations (in order to use the new C# 8 "nullable" feature), Resharper removes the `[CanBeNull]` attribute:

```
public static string? Test(string? arg)
{
    return arg;
}
```

However, if that attribute is removed then Resharper does not warn me about possible null-reference uses in other source files. (This would not be an issue if *all* the source files had `#nullable enable` specified, but because I am converting the files in a piecemeal fashion, there are many files that do not yet have `#nullable enable` specified, so the compiler will not warn me about possible null-reference uses - and neither will Resharper, because the `[CanBeNull]` was removed.)

So my question is this:

**Is there a way of stopping Resharper from removing the `[CanBeNull]` attribute when I type a `?` at the end of a reference type name?**

I've searched through all the Resharper options but I haven't managed to find one for this.

Comment: Have you tried setting `<Nullable>warnings</Nullable>`? That will enable nullable warnings without enabling nullable annotations, and you can still go through file-by-file and enable nullable annotations. It might bring up a lot of unnecessary warnings, though.

Comment: @canton7 Unfortunately, the `<Nullable>warnings</Nullable>` setting doesn't work for our .Net 4.8 projects - the setting is ignored. (I assume that you mean the setting in the `.csproj` file.)

Comment: Ah, you're still on an old-style csproj, rather than an SDK-style? Apparently `<Nullable>` in an old-style csproj affects MSBuild, but not VS ([link](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5551)). The SDK-style ones are significantly nicer if you can do the switch, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, we intend to port our code base to .Net Core 3.x at some point, but since we have literally millions of lines of code, that's going to take some considerable time!

Comment: Note that the SDK-style csproj supports .NET Framework just fine -- it's not tied to .NET Core in any way. Set your `<TargetFramework>` to `net46` or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the question on the Resharper support forums, and have received a solution:

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006676140-How-to-stop-Resharper-from-removing-CanBeNull-when-typing-at-the-end-of-a-reference-type-name-

To fix it:

1. Go to Extensions -> Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Editor Behavior -> C#
2. Locate and turn off the option "*Annotate nullability on '!'/'?' after type name*".
3. Locate and turn off the option "*Annotate nullability on '!'/'?' at other positions*"